# Migrating a 32bit qt application to 64 bit platform

Tags: visual-studio, qt, compilation, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have an application developed with qt. I want to make a 64 bit version of it on windows. I am using visual studio 2012.

how do I use the VS compiler to compile the qt source code and my source code for a 64 bit target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to build the Qt sources, because someone already has:

http://tver-soft.org/qt64

http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtx64/

Download and install the binaries.

Then make sure the kit is found and configured in Qt Creator or in Visual Studio.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that there are official 64-bit builds for VS 2013.